# An idiom describing the end of argument?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

If some people arguing about something, a common rumor, for example which is not yet confirmed. But when the concerned party had said its word and ends the argument forever, and people stopped arguing about it. 
What we shall say in this case

> The committee settled the argument.

Is the settle the suitable verb here. 
I belive there should be an idiom in English describing this, as it does exist in Arabic.

Comment: *Settle* works.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is out of my question boundary, but can you please recommend me an idioms dictionary, for such cases?

Comment: recommend an idiom to me

Comment: "Put the kibosh on". I just leave this here as a fun way of saying "put an end to". Though it doesn't necessarily refer to an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might say that the concerned party gave the ***[last word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20word)***:

> 2 a : the power of final decision
>   b : a definitive statement or treatment • *this study will surely be the last word on the subject for many years*
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20word)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You could use the expression

***[have the final say](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+final+say)***

> 1. To say the final words in an argument or discussion, especially ones that decisively or conclusively end it. *The whole meeting just descended into chaos as everyone tried to have the final say. David is so smug and always has to have the final say in every debate.*
> 2. To have the authority to decide how something ultimately happens or is done. *As the editor in chief, I have the final say on the layout design for every issue.*

So,

- the committee had the final say on the argument.